# Copy paste a single value from within a cell to another cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, copy, office365

Good day,

I wanted to ask a small question regarding a copy and paste issue that I am having.

In Row 79, column J of my Excel spread sheet I have the following information

```
['0', 0],['0.5', 0],['1', 0],['1.5', 0],['2', 8],['2.5', 14],['3', 25],['3.5', 45],['4', 75],['4.5', 130],['5', 192]
```

What I would like to do is to copy and paste the value that corresponds to 2.5 to the same row (Row 79) but into column W.

How could I pick out that specific value within the cell at Row 79, Column J and move it into Row 79, Column W.

I am looking for a way that allows me to copy the value that corresponds with the 2.5 value for all rows in Column J and copy that value into the same row but in Column W.

Please note, that the number that corresponds with 2.5 will not always be equal to 14 so I need something that can be dynamic in nature.

I am also looking for a formula-based result rather than a VBA based result.

Thanks for having me on the board and thanks for any help in advance. Its GREATLY appreciated because manually trying to do this will take days.

A big thanks again.

Incidentally, I am using Microsoft 365 in a Windows 11 environment.

Comment: May be I am not understanding it clearly, but could you confirm does this work on your end: `=LET(x, TEXTSPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(J79,"],[","]|["),,"|"), --TEXTBEFORE(TEXTAFTER(FILTER(x, ISNUMBER(SEARCH("'2.5'",x))),", "),"]"))`

Comment: Or, may be if the char len is always `2` for the before commas, then : `=LET(x, TEXTSPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(J79,"],[","]|["),,"|"), --MID(FILTER(x,1-ISERR(FIND("'2.5'",x))),8,3))` note that you cant use a formula to copy, formula cant copy, copying is either manual or using vba, formula can only return you an output automatically, if conditions are met. That said the given formulas needs to be placed in cell `W79`

Comment: Your first solution worked perfectly.  I am still breaking it down but I have a couple of million cells to copy with this method.  I only added a '$' with the J79 to read $J79 so that I could copy the formula while holding the J column constant and it worked like a charm. Thanks for the help. It is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have understood correctly, one can extract the required value from the blocks which contains `'2.5',` however as per it mentions about copying, one should note that `Excel Formulas` cannot copy anything it just outputs a value when placed in a cell following certain conditions.

To find and automatically paste in specific cell needs `VBA` or by doing it manually. That said, I tried to attempt by using the following formula entered in cell `W79` to return the output. Maybe I am mistaking somewhere, but appreciate if OP highlights, what they are specifically trying to accomplish.

[image]

---

```
=LET(
     x, TEXTSPLIT(J79,"]","],[",1),
     --RIGHT(FILTER(x,1-ISERR(FIND("'2.5',",x))),3))
```

---

Or,

```
=LET(
     x, TEXTSPLIT(J79,"]","],[",1), 
     --TEXTAFTER(FILTER(x,1-ISERR(FIND("'2.5',",x))),", "))
```

---

Comment: As noted above, your first solution worked perfectly. I am still breaking it down but I have a couple of million cells to copy with this method. I only added a '$' with the J79 to read $J79 so that I could copy the formula while holding the J column constant and it worked like a charm. Thanks for the help. It is greatly appreciated.

Comment: @MedicineMan then you should look into `Power Query` right option, formulas may work at certain rows without any issue, but `PQ` can handle lot many rows, you raise a post with the `Power Query`, but note users may like to see what you have tried.

Comment: @MedicineMan glad to know it worked, btw i just removed the `SUBSTITUTE()` from the formula its redundant and not required. realized later 

Comment: Great.  I will give it a try to remove the substitute portion.  I will take your advice as well.  Not having using excel for some time and was completely stuck.  Thanks for the lesson and the help.

Comment: @MedicineMan no issues at all.